# Approximately how many lockers are there in one map of Dead by Daylight?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

I know this number can change based on the map, so I'd like to ask specifically about the MacMillan maps. with the new locker perk for The Legion, I'd like to know the answer to this question for the average map size.

Answer (score -1):

There is no fixed number, since this depends on the map on which you play.

For example, on the map of the huntress (I don't remember the name) there is an area with 6 lockers together. On the plague map, in the downtown area below, there are a few together. apart from those that leave in different locations too.

So there is no exact number, but we could say that in almost all maps, there is an area with 3 or 4 lockers together, or more, in addition to the ticket offices that are scattered around the map.